# Horizontally shifting subfloat captions in figure environment!

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

When using subfloat, the caption centers with regards to the figure width. However I want to center it with regards to the axes.  How to horizontally shift the captions (manually) for all the subfloats in a figure environment, to center to axes?

(My figures are in PDF format.)

[image: caption is not centered to axes] 
[image: caption centered to axes]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To shift the sub-captions to the left or right one could use the `margin=` option offered by the `caption` package. The following example document will shift the sub-captions 2cm to the right:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{oneside,margin={2cm,0cm}}
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{test1}}
  \hspace{1cm}
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{test1}}
  \caption{Caption text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Please note the usage of the additional option `oneside` which will make sure that the extra sub-caption margins will not be swapped in `twoside` documents.

[image]

(Of course this trick will work in conjunction with the `subcaption` package as well.)

Comment: Oh yes, this works perfectly. Been looking for something like this for a long time. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to change the format of your figure calls to \bxfigure{caption}{image}, the boxhandler package can do this for you with their \FigureDeadMargin setting and the use of a \rule.  It would look something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{boxhandler}
\begin{document}

\captionStyle{n}{}
\FigureDeadMargin 8ex
\bxfigure{This is the caption that should be offset 8ex to the right}
{\fbox{FIGURE DATA GOES HERE}\rule{8ex}{0ex}}

\end{document}
```

Note that the caption will be page left-right centered, while the figure will be shifted to the left by the offset.

[image]