# How to automatically align subfloat captions to xlabel of PGFplots?

Tags: pgfplots, horizontal-alignment, subfloats, subcaption, tikzscale

Subfloat captions are not usually aligned with their corresponding xlable in PGFplots.
[image]
[image]

One way is to manually move the captions horizontally to align them. For example, (copied from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99959/24167))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{oneside,margin={2cm,0cm}}
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{test1}}
  \hspace{1cm}
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{test1}}
  \caption{Caption text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, this process would be tedious if there are too many figures in the document each requiring separate alignment.

Is there any possible way to automatically align subcaptions to (detect if any and) center to their x axis o PGFplots?

**EDIT:**

Using `tikzscale` to resize the figures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{oneside}
  \subfloat[]{ %
    \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{plot1.tikz}
  }%
  \hspace{1cm}
  \subfloat[]{%
    \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{plot2.tikz}
  }
  \caption{Caption text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

where *plot1.tikz* is:

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel={$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$}
  ]
  \addplot {x^2 - x +4};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
```

and *plot2.tikz* :

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$\sin(x)$
  ]
  \addplot {sin(deg(x))};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
```

The result will be:
[image]

Comment: That would be the wrong direction. TeX just sees a black box to be captioned and doesn't know what the content is. You need to go the other way namely centering the picture wrt to the axis not axis + ylabel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the options `trim axis left` and/or `trim axis right` for `tikzpicture`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{oneside}
  \subfloat[]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel={$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$},
    width=5cm
  ]
  \addplot {x^2 - x +4};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
  \hspace{2cm}
  \subfloat[]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$\sin(x)$,
    width=5cm
  ]
  \addplot {sin(deg(x))};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
  \caption{Caption text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution. Is there any way to align them when using `tikzscale` as well, where `trim axis left` or `trim axis right` are disabled?

Comment: I am not familiar with `tikzscale`; is that an option for `tikzpicture`, or are you referring to the `scale` option? Can you please provide an example document using that option?

Comment: `tikzscale` is a package which modifies `\includegraphics` to input `tikzpicture` pictures to occupy exactly the specified width and height (the whole picture including labels and titles). The documentation can be found <a href="http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzscale">Here</a>. For proper operation of `tikzscale` the options '`width',`height`,`trim axis left` and `trim axes right` must be disabled. I edited the post to include an example.

Comment: @M.Reza Pgfplots supports `width` and `height` keys so you don't need to use `tikzscale` pgfplots graphics (pure tikz pictures don't have that hence the `tikzscale` package). Supply it to the axis options and you are free to use trimming.